# Simple AHK script, trying to understand if this is expected or if I'm doing something wrong

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

Here is the code:

```
*Lalt::return

#if GetKeyState("Lalt", "P")

a::
   
   b::
   
   if GetKeyState("shift", "P")
   
   send ^+{%A_ThisHotkey%}
   
   else
   
      Send ^{%A_ThisHotkey%}
return

#if
```

in the code above, when I press Lalt+a it sends Ctrl+a which is expected, but when I press Lalt+Shift+a it only sends Shift+a, shouldn't it send Ctrl+Shift+a ?!. I also noticed that if I press the Shift key first before pressing on Lalt it sends Alt+Shift+a. It sounds to me like the Shift key trumps Alt or it gets sent to my machine before going through AH
K.

tried to use the * modifier and {blind} with send, but still when I press Lalt+shift+a, it only sends Shift+a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHK (and Windows) is very finicky with modifiers keys, so it's normal to have issues when working with them.

First thing is that when you press `Shift`, the AHK hook changes from `a::` to `+a::`, as now another hot key combination is being pressed.

The other issue is that `{%A_ThisHotkey%}` in the context of `+a::` don't work as expected, returning `+a`, it just seems to return nothing.

Finally, this would be the result:

```
*Lalt::return

#if GetKeyState("Lalt", "P")


a::

   b::

      Send ^{%A_ThisHotkey%}
      
return

+a::  
   +b::
      Send ^%A_ThisHotkey%
   
return

#if
```

For debuging, I used this env configurations:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
KeyHistory
```